# Class 'Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler' not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

While trying to access>> http://localhost:phpmyadmin It's showing following Error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler' not
>   found in
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\ExceptionServiceProvider.php
>   on line 68

```
Open: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php
        if (!is_null($route)) {
            return $route->bind($request);
        }
        $others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);
        if (count($others) > 0) {
            return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
        }
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
    protected function checkForAlternateVerbs($request)
```

I have updated the composer. Still showing the error.

How do I resolve it?

Comment: You need to show the code

Comment: Which part of code you want to see?

Comment: The part from where exception is coming. (From the log you posted, "ExceptionServiceProvider.php on line 68")

Comment: Added to the Question .. Please see once.

Comment: Hi @Hola, how you solved this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
php artisan cache:clear
```